# JavaScript Parallax Function - How to Create Multiple Instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I'm making a custom parallax background JavaScript. At this point, it works great (just as intended). Unfortunately I'm new to JavaScript, so my knowledge is limited. The script I've written works great when only one instance is required (which is the way it's written). 
I want it to be able to work with multiple instances.

Right now, it finds the element with the class `parallax` and does it's magic. Obviously, with the way it's written, having multiple instances/elements of the class "parallax" will not work. I'm absolutely stumped on how to take the next step and apply my function to all instances individually. I've searched plenty, but still have no idea how to proceed.
The code is attached. Eventually, I will make a separate function for `$(document).ready`, `$(window).resize`, and `$(window).scroll` to save on processing power, but I do not want to do that until I'm closer to the finish line.

How can I format this script to work with multiple instances (multiple parts of the webpage that will utilize the script for the effect)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    parallaxReady();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
    parallaxReady();
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    parallaxReady();
    });
    function parallaxResize() {}
    function parallaxScroll() {}
    function parallaxReady() {              
        $(".parallax img").width('100%');                                               // This is for window resizing
        $(".parallax img").height('auto');                                              // This is for window resizing
        var winHeight = window.innerHeight;                                             //
        var offset = $(".parallax").offset();                                           //
        var fromTop = offset.top;                                                       //
        var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;                                             //
        var ratio = -.7;                                                                // I would like to set this individually
        var verticalAlign = 0;                                                          //
        var travel = 0;                                                                 //
        var containerHeight = $(".parallax").css("height");                             // Get container height
        var containerWidth = $(".parallax").css("width");                               // Get container width
            containerHeight = parseInt(containerHeight, 10);                            // Remove px
            containerWidth = parseInt(containerWidth, 10);                              // Remove px
        var imageHeight = $(".parallax img").css("height");                             // Get image height
        var imageWidth = $(".parallax img").css("width");                               // Get image width
            imageHeight = parseInt(imageHeight, 10);                                    // Remove px        
            imageWidth = parseInt(imageWidth, 10);                                      // Remove px

        if (winHeight > containerHeight){                                               // If the container is smaller than Viewport
            travel = (winHeight - containerHeight);                                     // Set travel distance

            if (imageHeight < (containerHeight + (travel * -ratio))){                   // If image is too short
                $(".parallax img").height(containerHeight + (travel * -ratio) + 'px');  // Resize image to height needed
                imageHeight = (containerHeight + (travel * -ratio));                    // Update variable
                $(".parallax img").width('auto');                                       // Set image width to auto
                imageWidth = $(".parallax img").css("width");                           // Update variable
                imageWidth = parseInt(imageWidth, 10);                                  // Remove px
                }
            else {
                verticalAlign = (imageHeight - (containerHeight + (travel * -ratio)))   // Else if image is tall enough, center it vertically
                }                       
            }
        else {                                                                          // Else if container is taller than Viewport
            travel = (containerHeight) - winHeight;                                     // Set travel distance
            $(".parallax img").height(winHeight + (travel * -ratio) + 'px');            // Resize image to height needed
            $(".parallax img").width('auto');                                           // Set image width to auto
            imageWidth = $(".parallax img").css("width");                               // Update variable
            imageWidth = parseInt(imageWidth, 10);                                      // Remove px

            if (imageWidth < containerWidth){                                           // If image width is too short
                $(".parallax img").width(containerWidth);                               // Set image width to 100% container width
                $(".parallax img").height('auto');                                      // Set height to auto
                verticalAlign = (imageHeight - (winHeight + (travel * -ratio)))         // Center it vertically
                }
            }           

        if (imageWidth > containerWidth){                                               // If image width is wider than container
            $(".parallax img").css('left',((imageWidth - containerWidth) * -.5) + 'px');// Center image horizontally
            }
        else {                                                                          // Else if image is not wider than container
            $(".parallax img").css('left','0');                                         // Reset to 0
            }

        var alignment = ((fromTop - winHeight) + containerHeight);                      // The initial height reference for image

        var newPos = (scrollPos * ratio) - ((alignment * ratio) + (verticalAlign *.5)); // Position for Image based on our criteria
        $(".parallax img").css('bottom',newPos + 'px');                                 // Set the new position for image

        $("#debug").text("Scroll Height: " + scrollPos + " | Window Height: " + winHeight + " | DIV Height: " + containerHeight + " | Image Height " + imageHeight + " | Offset: " + fromTop + " | Travel: " + travel + " | Alignment: " + alignment + " | Vertical Align: " + verticalAlign);
        }   
</script>   
<style scoped>
html, body {padding:0;margin:0;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#debug {padding:15px;background:#000;font-size:12px;color:#fff;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:1000;opacity:.5;}
.spacer {height:70vh;background: #444;}
.longer {height:100vh;}
.parallax {overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
.parallax img {width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
.parallax div {width:40%;margin:10% auto;padding:5%;position:relative;color:#fff;font-size:36px;text-align:center;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
.parallax div p {padding:10px 0;margin:0;font-size:15px;text-align:justify;}
</style>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="parallax">
        <img alt="parallax" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2012/09/21/15744/3ad1c548edfc58f499feda5b042fb857.jpg">  
        <div>
            This is Random Text
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel id errem fierent sensibus, liber similique voluptatibus sit te, cum ea aliquip persequeris. Eam ne hinc labitur suscipit. Te laudem scaevola sea, esse nibh maiorum quo te. Sit enim regione ei, pro te accusamus definitiones. Maiorum perpetua oportere pro eu. Ea mel homero inermis insolens, ut adhuc putent qui.</p>
            <p>Apeirian platonem interpretaris eu quo, wisi audire appetere sea ad. Vis cibo congue libris ut, has ea erat maiorum percipitur. Ius ut doming inciderint, affert eirmod cu sed. Ne mel falli partiendo, ei agam minim legimus sit. Quem omnis mundi pro in, ei viderer mediocritatem quo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer longer"></div>
    <div id="debug"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fiddle your code please.

Comment: OP should fiddle it of course, but c'mon, this just took me 45 seconds to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/L2Lhz8vp/

Answer (score 0):

I like the effect! There are a few common patterns in javascript to do modules like this. One way is as follows.

**Make your div.parallax the outer container of all everything required, like:**

```
<div class='parallax'>
    content
</div>
```

**Make a `parallax` "class".** In javascript a "class" is just an object that follows certain patterns. This will be the only object exposed to the global scope. Your parallaxReady() function is dangerously close to this already (that's good).

**Make parallax.init() or something similar.** The function will accept an `options` hash. You would call this function for each parallax div on your page like this:

```
$('div.parallax').forEach(function(element) {
    parallax.init({
        element: element,
        image: "/path/to/my/image.jpg",
    });
});
```

**Rewrite your code into parallax.init()**. Anywhere you're currently referencing `$(".parallax")` or `$(".parallax img")` or whatever would change to refer to the dynamic element passed in instead. For example, this line:

```
$(".parallax img").width('100%');
```

would change to

```
options.element.width('100%');
```

parallax.init() would create whatever other elements needed inside the parallax container div - like the image div, the spacers, whatever. It will also set up whatever variables and stuff it needs, and then register a scroll event. It seems like most of the code you currently have in parallaxReady would end up in this scroll event within parallax.init().

parallax.init() could also return some sort of identifier so that you could use it to call parallax.stop() if you implemented that.  Or you could make this whole thing an actual jQuery plugin.

I hope that helps get you started.

Comment: Hey @pabo , Thanks for the reply! I like where you're going with this... I'm going to be away for most of the day but when I return, I have some questions/ideas for you.